# Laravel Sanctum Token API Authentication Not Working in Postman

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to utilize Sanctum for an API only application. I am not using it for a SPA. I have a single end point set up and protected by the Sanctum middleware. I am creating a user and a token for said user through the tinker cli tool. I then paste the token into Postman under the bearer token selection within the authorization tab. However, when I submit the request I get an unauthenticated error. Not quite sure what I am doing incorrect here. Followed the documentation provided very closely as well as the sparse videos I could find. Here are some code snippets. I appreciate the insight here.

API.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->apiResource('/documents','DocumentHandlerController');
```

Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Return 401 when not authorized
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function handle($request)
    {
        return response()->json(
            ['message'=>'Unauthorized']
            ,Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }
}
```

Function from my controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->json(['Success'],Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Comment: I stand under correction here but I experienced a similar issue to you a few weeks back. What I THINK the issue is that Sanctum makes use of cookie-based auth and requires the CSRF protection and stateful management in the web.php. Are you using the sanctum cookie auth or are you making use of api tokens in this instance? I eventually resolved this issue by making use of the web.php instead of the api.php. Im not sure how helpful this is but that worked for me

Comment: can you explain, how did you create token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue where I got the response `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}`.

For me it was because in my `.env` file, my APP_URL was `https://www.example.com` and I was trying to access the API via the URL `https://example.com`.

When I changed the URL that made the API call to `https://www.example.com` it was working.

Comment: I don't have access to the code base anymore, but I almost certain this was the issue. I had added 'guard' =>  'api' like others mentioned and that still didn't fix the issue. I think this is correct.

Comment: @KileyPoole Glad to hear that I might have helped you! Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same Issue but I solved it by add to headers: `Accept with value application/json`.

That's the best solution I found maybe others have another solution.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I killed full day when trying to solve this problem. In my case, the problem was in the Apache config. I hope this helps you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same problem. After some investigation it seems the problem happens there:
https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/commit/f5695aecc547138c76bc66aaede73ba549dabdc5

During the refactoring they forgot to include default guard definition.

Just add this at the end of config/sanctum.php for api guard:

```
'guard' =>  'api'
```

Comment: This worked wonders

Answer (score 0):

For some reason  `auth:sanctum` doesn't work for API authentication. Same problem happened with me then i saw this issue on [github](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1177) . 
 i see two solutions at this point

1. [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth)
2. [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use it with postman/insomnia

remember to add the referer in headers:

in my situation, it's local dev so the referer header is "localhost"  because my  SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS env variables is equal to localhost

[header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXe7X.png)